# Time difference in HIVE

Tags: time, hive

I am trying to find the difference between two timestamps in Hive. But the date_time field is STRING, so I need to convert it to date_time format before finding the time difference.

This is the code I am using, but I get NULL.

```
   SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE("2016-12-30 10:39:46"),'HH:MM:SS') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE("2016-12-30 10:39:31"),'HH:MM:SS');
```

I would need the difference to be 15 seconds.

Any suggestions would be great !!

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-12-30 10:39:46') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-12-30 10:39:31');
```

It should give time difference in seconds.

Comment: Please note that unix_timestamp() is not deterministic and its value is not fixed for the scope of a query execution, therefore prevents proper optimization of queries.